# Почему список ul уходит чуть вниз?

Tags: html, список

Почему список ul уходит чуть вниз оставляю сверху место, как убрать это пустое место. Вот код

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li>Квартиры</li>
<li>Новостройки</li>
<li>Нежилые помещения</li>
<li>Дома и коттеджи</li>
<li>Дачи</li>
<li>Земельные участки</li>
<li>Найти</li>
<li>Добавить объявление</li>
<li>Поиск на карте</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
или
```

[reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html)

http://jsfiddle.net/S7KVX/

Сначала всегда следует подключать CSS Reset, а потом все остальные стили. Да также добавлю использование reset.css не обязательно - это личное дело каждого